# Can you determine if a note is sharp vs flat if it doesn't feature in the scale?

Tags: theory, scales

[image]

Given the scale **Lydian** in the key of **C** we can determine that the **F#** (rather than **Gb**) is indeed an **F#** as it doesn't appear elsewhere in the scale.

How can you determine if a note is sharped or flatted if it doesn't exist in the scale? For example if **Ab** should be a **G#**?

Does it even make sense to imagine out of scale notes like this or am I thinking about it incorrectly?

Comment: Related: https://music.stackexchange.com/q/69668/39614

Comment: Looks like these notes are called accidentals, I need to do some reading.

Comment: look also here: https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/23976/why-do-notes-have-multiple-names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard 7 note diatonic scales need to contain one of each letter name. Where there are chromatic notes, they will depend on what the original note was that's changed. For example, in key C, where the harmony makes an F minor chord, the changed note will be A♭, whereas the same pitch note making a C augmented chord will have the G changed to G♯.

When an interval is changed from major to minor, or diminished, the original note will be flattened or double flattened. If it's P5 and that gets augmented, it'll be sharpened. Not written as the next note up flattened. That way, readers can see how the harmony has changed, technically.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I got a little lost when F minor was brought up, are you saying that the context of the rest of the music determines how it's notated?

Comment: Not really. More related to which note has actually been changed to form the harmony which needs the chromatic note. In F minor, there isn't G#, because it's spelled F Ab C. Hinges on what the original diatonic note would be before the change. There, it's A, not G.

Comment: hmm okay, what do you mean by harmony because it seems to have different meanings depending on context? I'll do some more reading tonight since I think I'm missing something.

Comment: I think what I'm missing is why F minor, how does that relate to this scale?

Comment: It's part of what's called the *parallel * key of C minor. F minor is found in pieces in C. That was just one example.

Comment: I'll look into it, I was aware of relative minors however those contain the same notes.